# Is $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}$ uniform convegent

Tags: uniform-convergence

Consider the functions

$f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

for $n=1,2,...$ defined by $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}$

Give all the points in $\mathbb{R}$ where $f_n$ converges poinwisely

does ${f_n}$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

I think since $f_n(0)=0$

then $\lim f_n=0$ as

$n \rightarrow \infty$

But I am not sure how you would show it is uniform convergent.

Comment: It is not. For all $n$ you have $$\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}} |f_n(x) - 0(x)| = + \infty$$ and this does not approach to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Now, check the definition of uniform convergence, and conclude.

Comment: But why is there a 0 next to the x in  sup$|f_n(x)-0(x)|=\infty$

Comment: It's the zero function mapping every number to $0$. This is the pointwise limit, remember?

Comment: I see. So you map every number to zero the point-wise limit. But I though $\forall \epsilon >0  \exists N$ such that you have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $ \forall n \ge N$

Comment: But here f is replaced by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function convege pointwise to $0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ because
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}  |f_{n}(x)|=\Bigg| \frac{x}{n} \cdot \sin \Big( \frac{x}{n} \Big) \Bigg| \leq \Big| \frac{x}{n} \Big| \rightarrow_{n\to \infty}0 $$
However there no uniform convegent becaue for e.g $\epsilon=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we can choose $x_0 := \frac{n\pi}{2}$ : 
$$ f_{n}(x)= \frac{      \frac{n\pi}{2}    }{n} \cdot \sin \Big( \frac{           \frac{n\pi}{2}       }{n} \Big) = \frac{\pi}{2} >1 $$
So $f_n\rightarrow 0$ but not uniformly.